# 301 redirect with exceptions not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm really stuck with now so would appreciate any help.

I am trying to redirect a site to another domain but with some exceptions.  Here is the code I have now in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/sitemap/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/contact-us/
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.newsite.com/folder/$0 [R=301,L]

Redirect 301 /sitemap/ http://www.newsite.com/sitemap/
Redirect 301 /contact-us/ http://www.newsite.com/contact-us/
```

Any ideas why this may not be working?

The home page and the sitemap and contact us pages redirect fine but all other pages are not redirected.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Move the Redirect lines higher

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /sitemap/ http://www.newsite.com/sitemap/
Redirect 301 /contact-us/ http://www.newsite.com/contact-us/
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/sitemap/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/contact-us/
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.newsite.com/folder/$0 [R=301,L]
```

I tried this on my apache server and it worked

```
http://www.oldsite.com/sitemap/ => http://www.newsite.com/sitemap/
http://www.oldsite.com/contact-us/ => http://www.newsite.com/contact-us/
http://www.oldsite.com/test => http://www.newsite.com/folder/test
```